# Form serialization with '&' character in summernote code text

Tags: jquery, serialization, summernote

I have a form with a few summernote divs and I am trying to post their texts through ajax and form serialization.

the summernote divs are like this:

```
<div class="description" id='a_unique_id'></div>
```

The summernotes are initialized like this:

```
$('.description').each(function () {

    $('#' + this.id).summernote({
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
        ],
        disableDragAndDrop: true
    });
});
```

And the serialization code is like this:

```
var descriptions = '';

$('.description').each(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var code = $('#' + id).code();
    if(code != '<p><br></p>'){
        descriptions += '&' + id + '=' + code;
    }
});

var data = $('#ajax_form').serialize() + descriptions;
```

Now lets suppose one of the summernotes code is like "some text &another text". I mean, the text has a '&' character on it.

The serialization doesn't work!

How can I deal with this scenario?

After @mhodges answer, I changed the serialization code to:

```
descriptions += '&' + id + '=' + encodeURIComponent(code)
```

And now it is working as I would like it to be.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, I want to send the serialized data using ajax post to a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `encodeURIComponent(code)`

`descriptions += '&' + id + '=' + encodeURIComponent(code);`

Then you will just need to decode it in your server-side script

[encodeURIComponent docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: +1 because you gave me the direction, but the solution is not correct. I used the 'encodeURIComponent' over 'code', because I already concatenate the character '&' to 'descriptions' and encoding it would encode those characters too.

Comment: Will update so that it is correct. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work.

```
descriptions += '&' + id + '=' + encodeURIComponent($('.description').summernote('code'));
```